# How to create white border around bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

For example I want a white border of 10pixel around all 4 side of the bitmap. I am not using it for imageview
I am currently using this code to crop image. May I know how I could add a white border into it?

```
public Bitmap scaleCenterCrop(Bitmap source, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
    int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();

    // Compute the scaling factors to fit the new height and width, respectively.
    // To cover the final image, the final scaling will be the bigger 
    // of these two.
    float xScale = (float) newWidth / sourceWidth;
    float yScale = (float) newHeight / sourceHeight;
    float scale = Math.max(xScale, yScale);

    // Now get the size of the source bitmap when scaled
    float scaledWidth = scale * sourceWidth;
    float scaledHeight = scale * sourceHeight;

    // Let's find out the upper left coordinates if the scaled bitmap
    // should be centered in the new size give by the parameters
    float left = (newWidth - scaledWidth) / 2;
    float top = (newHeight - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // The target rectangle for the new, scaled version of the source bitmap will now
    // be
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);

    // Finally, we create a new bitmap of the specified size and draw our new,
    // scaled bitmap onto it.
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I wrote a function for this:

```
private Bitmap addWhiteBorder(Bitmap bmp, int borderSize) {
    Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getHeight() + borderSize * 2, bmp.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, borderSize, borderSize, null);
    return bmpWithBorder;
}
```

Basically it creates a new Bitmap adding 2 * bordersize to each dimension and then paints the original Bitmap over it, offsetting it with bordersize.

Comment: This works when the imageview size is higher than the displayed image size and normal method for borders with background and padding fails since some parts are overfilled that the others. This method is perfect. kudos.

Comment: perfect code. borderSize need to be float to be used in drawBitmap() method

Comment: That seems a canvas border, and not a bitmap border, does it need a canvas for each bitmap? What if my canvas is the full screen with multiple bitmaps on it?

Answer (score 16):

As for a way of doing this. You make your bitmap bigger than the one your adding to it and then fill the canvas with the background you want. If you need to add other effects you can look into the canvas options for clipping the rect and adding rounded corners and such.

```
RectF targetRect = new RectF(left+10, top+10, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);
Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth+20, newHeight+20, source.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawBitmap(source, null, targetRect, null);
```

Comment: not working. image white border does not appear on 4 side. only a border for top and bottom

Comment: well you have the basic idea play around with the targetRect and bitmap size to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw 4 rectangles after painting your bitmap's stuff.

```
point 0,0,3,sizey
point 0,0,sizex,3
point 0,sizey-3,sizex,sizey
point sizex-3,0,sizex,sizey
```

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer is nice but in the cases that bitmap contains a transparent background, it fills all over the background of source bitmap with white pixels. so it doesn't work fine for all cases.

a better way to achieve this goal is using Canvas#drawLine method like the following code:

```
    Bitmap drawBorder(Bitmap source) {
    int width = source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, width, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(width, 0, width, height, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(width, height, 0, height, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, height, 0, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, null);

    return bitmap;
        }
```

in this way we first create a second bitmap using source bitmap width, height and config and use drawline() mathod four times to draw four lines using coordinates of end points of each line around the second bitmap and then draw the source bitmap on the second bitmap that must be returned.

Comment: target bitmap is not necessarily a square, border should be fit to shape of bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

A super easy way of doing it would be to set the ImageView background to white and add a padding value.

If that doesn't work, create a FrameLayout with w/h of wrap_content, set its background to white, put the ImageView in there, and set the ImageView's margins to the desired border width.

Answer (score 0):

Its not elegant but you can always just draw a rectangle behind it, you already have the code to do this and any performance impact is going to be unnoticeable

Comment: hi, can you show me how is it being done? i'm trying to figoure out how to draw a white recntage bg

Comment: Is it that you want a border around a square bitmap? If so just draw another square bitmap behind it

Comment: Its just canvas.drawRect if you are using the Canvas API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your targetRectangle 20px wider and 20px higher

```
RectF targetRect = new RectF(left, top, left + scaledWidth + 20, top + scaledHeight + 20);
```

and paint the background white

Comment: using it for map itemoverlay require bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will also add border to your canvas

```
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 0, paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, canvas.getHeight(), paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(),
                canvas.getHeight(), paint2);
        canvas.drawLine(canvas.getWidth(), 0, canvas.getWidth(),
                canvas.getHeight(), paint2);
```