# Android bitmap with border

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this function, with this function I can show an image with a little rotation.
I'm trying to display a white border arround the bitmap.

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.postRotate( rotation, center.x, center.y );
        m.postTranslate( ( position.x - center.x ) - xOffset , position.y - ( center.x ) );

        //  set the current position to the updated position
        positionMatrix.set( m );            
        renderAnimation();          
        c.drawBitmap( this.bitmap , positionMatrix, paint );
```

I'm trying to add the white border with this function: reference: [stackoverflow border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114085/how-to-create-white-border-around-bitmap)

```
    RectF targetRect = new RectF(left+10, top+10, left + scaledWidth, top + scaledHeight);
    Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.bitmap.getWith() +20, this.bitmap.getHeight() +20, this.bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dest);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, null, targetRect, null);
c.drawBitmap( this.bitmap , positionMatrix, paint );
```

But, not works, can some help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should follow these steps:

1. Create a bitmap that width = yourImageWidth + boderThick and  height= yourImageHeight + boderThick
2. Canvas draw a White rectangle (draw your background first)
3. Canvas draw your image (you need to center your image)

Maybe you made a mistake when calculating the side, or draw in a wrong order. Remember to use the same canvas when drawing. In your code i see you use c.draw and canvas.draw... That may cause the problem.

Refer to the code below:

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
 canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);//draw your bg
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 20, 20, paint);//draw your image on bg
```

Sorry, i don't have much time to check your calculated size. I hope this can help.

Comment: @NgyenDoanTung 
well, my problem maybe is:
Bitmap bmpWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.bitmap.getWidth() + 10 * 2, this.bitmap.getHeight() + 10 * 2, this.bitmap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpWithBorder);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 10, 10, null);//this is the white border
c.drawBitmap( this.bitmap , positionMatrix, paint ); //original image

how i can know if the canvas are joined?