# How to add border to bitmap image content instead of its background by using Canvas?

Tags: android, drawing, border, android-canvas

The feature of a bitmap image is that it has a **transparent** background and usually has a **rectangular** shape, so when we try to add a border to the image, instead of its content inside there will be a border, its background will have a border. For example, I have a bitmap image of a dog and I want it to have a **border** but instead, a rectangular background will have a **border**. I'm using **Canvas** to draw a bitmap and am having this problem. Can anyone help me?

Block code to create photo

```
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10); // set stroke width
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // set stroke color
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icons8_bus_36_2);
    tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    Rect rect = new Rect(
            10 / 2,
            10 / 2,
            tempCanvas.getWidth() - 10 / 2,
            tempCanvas.getHeight() - 10 / 2);
    tempCanvas.drawRect(rect,mPaint);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android bitmap with border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828102/android-bitmap-with-border)

Comment: I already try that solution bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this part:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(
            10 / 2,
            10 / 2,
            tempCanvas.getWidth() - 10 / 2,
            tempCanvas.getHeight() - 10 / 2);
```

change to

```
Rect rect = new Rect(
            10 / 2,
            10 / 2,
            (tempCanvas.getWidth() - 10) / 2,
            (tempCanvas.getHeight() - 10) / 2);
```

Thats because 10 is divided by two first

Also, draw bitmap first before you draw rect

OR

you could draw with this:

```
Path clipPath = new Path();
RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
```

Comment: Ty bro, you save my life.

Comment: No problem, you can accept my answer if it solved your issue. Happy coding